# Zend 1.11.9 Form decorators / captcha

Tags: php, zend-form, captcha, zend-decorators

In the new Zend Framework version 1.11.9 if I want to use a captcha in my form this can be a simple Figlet, the captcha is not shown in the rendered form. 
Has anyone encountered this issue, I've been searching and comparing it with the previous release, (Zend/Form/Element/Captcha.php) and what i noticed is that I must specify the Captcha decorator for this element. 
Is there a better solution, shouldn't this decorator been used by default?

```
   //Add a captcha
    $this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
        'label'      => 'Please enter the 5 letters displayed below:',
        'required'   => true,
        'captcha'    => array(
            'captcha' => 'Figlet',
            'wordLen' => 5,
            'timeout' => 300
        )
    ));
```

This is the code, if I use this in Zend 1.11.9 the capctha is not displayed,
What I had to do was to add 'decorators' to the options of teh capctha and had to specify there all the decorators.

```
   //Add a captcha
    $this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
        'label'      => 'Please enter the 5 letters displayed below:',
        'required'   => true,
        'captcha'    => array(
            'captcha' => 'Figlet',
            'wordLen' => 5,
            'timeout' => 300
        ),
        'decorators' => array('Captcha', 'Errors', 'Labels', etc)
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem. Posted a bug report on Zend Framework issue tracker: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11609

Hope it will get resolved soon. I've checked the 1.11.9 changelog: there was a change at the recaptcha component. Maybe that's the reason...

Comment: Yes, probably, Thanks for the reply..if you get some feedback please nootify me also. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this. To show you some code, in ZF 1.11.8 this works out of the box:

```
        $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
        'label' => 'Security Check',
        'required' => true,
        'captcha' => array(
            'captcha' => 'Image',
            'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/fonts/AllerDisplay.ttf',
            'fontSize' => '24',
            'wordLen' => 6,
            'height' => '50',
            'width' => '150',
            'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/captcha',
            'imgUrl' => Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() . '/images/captcha',
        )
    ));
```

In 1.11.9 it doesn't render the image tag. This behavoir is not limited to Zend_Captcha_Image as stated by the thread opener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of ZF
and

```
$captchaElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha
        (
            'signup',
            array('captcha' => array(
            'captcha' => 'Figlet',
            'wordLen' => 6,
            'timeout' => 600,       
            ))
        );
```

Show nothing =-(

This is the source on the page:

```
<dt id="signup-input-label"><label for="signup-input" class="required">Please type in the words below to continue</label></dt>

<dd id="signup-element">

<input type="hidden" name="signup[id]" value="9038166aac96370c73b9d474e8e20475" id="signup-id">

<input type="text" name="signup[input]" id="signup-input" value="">
```